# Can I say "徹底対策" instead of "徹底した対策"?

Tags: grammar

The full clause goes: "徹底した対策を講じるべきだ". I'm wondering if "徹底対策" is the same as "徹底した対策" and if there are any rules that I missed?

Answer (score 6):

Not likely. As far as I've ever heard, 徹底○○ is only possible in Japanese when ○○ is a stem of **suru-verb**.

> 徹底検証（する）
>   徹底比較（する）
>   徹底攻略（する）
>   徹底インタビュー（する）
>   徹底着こなし（する）

Although 対策 does have a verb sense, it appears as a noun, neither a verb nor a gerund in your context, thus you cannot replace the specific phrase with 徹底対策. Of course, rephrasing it to be:

> 徹底対策すべきだ

is valid.

Comment: "徹底対策" is perfectly valid Japanese, you can just google to find about 200,000 examples on the web.

Comment: @Ben I think OP is asking about whether they can use 徹底対策 in that specific context.

Comment: Do you really think that OP is asking about that, because I don't see that in your answer. It says "As far as I've ever heard, 徹底○○ is only possible in Japanese when ○○ is a stem of suru-verb", but 徹底対策 is a common phrase.

Comment: @Ben By "stem of suru-verb" I intend the part without suru. It's often said that that portion is a noun, but it's not a real noun in Japanese. It's compared to the "-ing" form of English verbs. For example you can say "trying" from "try", and make a sentence like "The right moral compass is trying hard to think about what customers want.", where it seems to play a noun's role. However, you can't say "give a trying", because it's not a real noun. Some words just use "-ing" form as a real noun (fitting, swimming) but others not. This is a crucial difference.